# get all localstorage items in order they were setted in

Tags: javascript, asp.net, model-view-controller

I want to know if there is a way to iterate through all of localstorage data in the order that they were putted in. The problem is that my keys are the id of the object and will not be in order.

I could have an item with the id 102 and the next one would be 3. I need to keep those id's because all of tr are identified with those id so that i can manipulate them so i need the localstorage.setitem(ID,data) to stay like this.

Is there a way to kind of like a push/pop the localstorage or like a localStorage.First() so that i can get my items in order ?

Comment: why don't you just add you id's in an array that you store in local storage? that way you can retrieve them in order.

Answer (score 0):

You are think about localStorage as array, but localStorage is a hash. Create your own variable in localStorage, and implement two methods: `push` and `pop`

```js
class LocalStorageStack {
  constructor(stackName) {
    this.stackName = stackName
  }

  push = (value) => {
    const stack = this.stack
    stack.push(value)
    this.stack = stack
  }

  pop = () => {
    const stack = this.stack
    const value = stack.pop()
    this.stack = stack
    return value
  }

  get stack() {
    return (window.localStorage[this.stackName] || '').split(',')
  }

  set stack(values) {
    window.localStorage[this.stackName] = values.join(',')
  }
}

const localStorageStack = new LocalStorageStack('myStack')

localStorageStack.push('111')
localStorageStack.push('112')
```

You can see in localStorage.myStack string variable == '111,112' and can pop values in backward order:

```js
localStorageStack.pop()
=> "112"
localStorageStack.pop()
=> "111"
```

```js
const windowLocalStorage = {}

class LocalStorageStack {
  constructor(stackName) {
    this.stackName = stackName
  }

  push = (value) => {
    const stack = this.stack
    stack.push(value)
    this.stack = stack
  }

  pop = () => {
    const stack = this.stack
    const value = stack.pop()
    this.stack = stack
    return value
  }

  get stack() {
    // Sorry, in the snippet localStorage is disabled by security reasons.
    // In this example local variable `windowLocalStorage emulates them
    return (windowLocalStorage[this.stackName] || '').split(',')
  }

  set stack(values) {
    windowLocalStorage[this.stackName] = values.join(',')
  }
}

const localStorageStack = new LocalStorageStack('my-stack')
console.log('push 111')
localStorageStack.push('111')
console.log('push 112')
localStorageStack.push('112')

console.log(localStorageStack.pop())
console.log(localStorageStack.pop())
```